# AvalonDock not Deserializing LayoutRoot orientation correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

This is frustrating, trying to figure out if this is a bug or I'm an idiot.

Using AvalonDock 3.3.17121.18230

I have a simple layout of Top, Bottom, Left/Center/Right panels. Everything is fine during initial load with the panel properties specified in XAML. After saving the layout using the .Serialize of XmlLayoutSerializer, everything in the text file looks fine. However, when re-loading the layout using Deserialize, the layout loads improperly and places the Top and Bottom panels to the left and right of the center Left/Center/Right panels.

My layout is one LayoutPanel with Orientation="Vertical", then nested inside are 3 LayoutPanels with Orientation="Horizontal". The first horizontal panel is just the TOP, followed by another horizontal panel containing the 3 Left/Center/Right panels, then the final horizontal panel which is the BOTTOM panel.

It appears that regardless of the Rootpanels layout orientation, it always deserializes it as horizontal, even though it explicitly says vertical.

[Initial load from XAML properties - all ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT7QJ.png)

Contents of serialized file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutRoot>
  <RootPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <LayoutAnchorablePane DockHeight="100">
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellTop" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellTop" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </LayoutPanel>
    <LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <LayoutAnchorablePane>
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellLeft" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellLeft" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
      <LayoutAnchorablePane>
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellMain" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellMain" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
      <LayoutAnchorablePane>
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellRight" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellRight" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </LayoutPanel>
    <LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <LayoutAnchorablePane>
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellBottom" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellBottom" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </LayoutPanel>
  </RootPanel>
  <TopSide />
  <RightSide />
  <LeftSide />
  <BottomSide />
  <FloatingWindows />
  <Hidden />
</LayoutRoot>
```

[After serializing, then deserializing - not ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOAxX.png)

Contents of serialized file after saving broken layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutRoot>
  <RootPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <LayoutAnchorablePane DockHeight="100">
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellTop" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellTop" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </LayoutPanel>
    <LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <LayoutAnchorablePane>
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellLeft" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellLeft" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
      <LayoutAnchorablePane>
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellMain" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellMain" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
      <LayoutAnchorablePane>
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellRight" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellRight" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </LayoutPanel>
    <LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <LayoutAnchorablePane>
        <LayoutAnchorable AutoHideMinWidth="100" AutoHideMinHeight="100" Title="ShellBottom" IsSelected="True" ContentId="ShellBottom" CanClose="False" />
      </LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </LayoutPanel>
  </RootPanel>
  <TopSide />
  <RightSide />
  <LeftSide />
  <BottomSide />
  <FloatingWindows />
  <Hidden />
</LayoutRoot>
```

As you can see, it's like the deserialize method doesn't care that RootPanel Orientation="Vertical" and always loads it like it is RootPanel Orientation="Horizontal"

Can someone please try this to sanity check me, or if I'm going about this wrong let me know. I'm just trying to save the state the is loaded from the XAML properties, I'd have to think this is a bug.

Here's the Grid control of my XAML

```
<Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Save Layout" Click="SaveButton_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Restore Layout" Click="RestoreButton_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Default Layout" Click="DefaultButton_Click"/>


        <avalonDock:DockingManager AllowMixedOrientation="True" x:Name="DManager" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Loaded="dockManager_Loaded">
            <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>

                <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                    <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockHeight="100">
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="ShellTop" ContentId="ShellTop">
                            <Button Content="TOP"/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>

                    </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>



                    <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="ShellLeft" ContentId="ShellLeft">
                                <Button Content="LEFT"/>
                            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>

                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="ShellMain" ContentId="ShellMain">
                                <Button Content="MIDDLE"/>
                            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="ShellRight" ContentId="ShellRight">
                                <Button Content="RIGHT"/>
                            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>

                    </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>


                    <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="ShellBottom" ContentId="ShellBottom">
                            <Button Content="BOTTOM"/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>

                    </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>



                </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>


            </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
```

Code-Behind

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlLayoutSerializer layoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(DManager);
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test.txt"))
    {
        layoutSerializer.Serialize(writer);
    }
}

private void RestoreButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlLayoutSerializer layoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(DManager);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test.txt"))
    {
        layoutSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolkit v3.4 already has a fix for a vertical orientation upon deserializing. Toolkit v3.4 is available today, june 5th 2017.
I suggest you try with it.

――――
*Get more controls, features, updates and technical support with [Xceed Toolkit Plus for WPF](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compare%20Editions)*

Comment: So bizarre, first time I ever used AvalonDocks was last thursday, ran into this issue, and it's fixed in today's release. However, I think they messed up because it claims Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit is a dependency, but there is no nuget package, so the update just breaks code.

Comment: I got it to work, although I had to manually add the nuget package for "Extended.Wpf.Toolkit". The updated AvalonDock nuget package listed it as a dependency but does not bring it in.